# Load custom images in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, networking, tensorflow

I`m new to tensorflow and python and I created a feed forward neural network with tensorflow that will help me to classify two groups of images. One group represents images of myself and another group represents images of a different person (I know convolutional network is better for this kind of problem but for the sake of learning I approached the FF network). All my images are stored in two separate directories. I`m trying to load the images for training and feed them into the NN. My images are 272x272px RGB so for this, the input layer should have 73984 neurons. I`m not able to load the images and feed them through the network.

I tried using this approach:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once("images/train/resized/*.jpg"))

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3) 
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) 
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [272, 272])
```

and then, when I run:

```
sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict={x: resized_image, y: 1})
```

I gen "The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object" error

Is there a better way to do it or what am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resized_image` variable is a tensor as you have initialized it to `tf.image.resize_images(image, [272, 272])`  ... your feed has to be a numpy array whose shape has to match the tensor `x` that you have defined in the code 
For example if in your case `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 272, 272, 3))`
 and then you have to give it bacth of images which has to be of shape (bacth_number, 272, 272, 3)

I would suggest you following code for reading the image ... take this code as an example

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread(path_to_the_image)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 272, 272, 3))
```

and when running it in the session:

```
sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict={x: image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])), y: 1})
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when running your code, my network structure will not allow me to compute the sum of the first layer because the number of neurons defined does not match with the actual input data. What should be the number of input neurons then?

Comment: make your input tensor to `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (272, 272))` and use PIL to read image in gray scale `gray_image = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')` and then feed the tensor `x` the `gray_image`   your input neurons depends on the shape of tensor `x`

Comment: Thank you for your time!